# Reactjs: ReferenceError: kendo is not defined

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui

I am using kendo-ui in my react project. Code for importing and using the Menu component is as below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Menu, MenuItem } from '@progress/kendo-layout-react-wrapper';

const AppHeader = () => {
    return (
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem>
                Test Item
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    )
}

export default AppHeader;
```

It compiles fine, but throws the following error while rendering:

```
ReferenceError: kendo is not defined
Menu../node_modules/@progress/kendo-layout-react-wrapper/dist/es/menu/menu.js.Menu.componentDidMount
E:/projects/eucerin/node_modules/@progress/kendo-layout-react-wrapper/dist/es/menu/menu.js:31
  28 | Menu.prototype.componentDidMount = function () {
  29 |     var domNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
  30 |     var _a = this.props, children = _a.children, widgetRef = _a.widgetRef, props = __rest(_a, ["children", "widgetRef"]);
> 31 |     this.widgetInstance = new kendo.ui.Menu(domNode, props);
  32 |     _super.prototype.componentDidMount.call(this);
  33 | };
  34 | Menu.prototype.componentWillReceiveProps = function (nextProps) {
```

I think I am missing a dependency here. Could anyone please let me know?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and asked the questions [React Kendo UI TreeView throws 'kendo is not defined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50646810/react-kendo-ui-treeview-throws-kendo-is-not-defined)

I found the solution from the KendoUI plunker example [TreeView Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)

The Kendo UI instruction is:

```
Dependencies
The TreeView package requires you to install the following peer dependencies in your application:
```

- @progress/kendo-ui

We have to install it but that's not enough. What KendoUI team did is import `@progress/kendo-ui` in the code explicitly:

```
import kendo from '@progress/kendo-ui';
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Plunkr link does not take you to treeview

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
For some reason, I had to import kendo this way :

```js
import from '@progress/kendo-ui';
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

From the [source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@progress/kendo-layout-react-wrapper), you also need 1 base dependency to use `kendo-layout-react-wrapper`:

```
@progress/kendo-base-component-react-wrapper
```

To install and save as dependency, use:

```
npm install --save @progress/kendo-base-component-react-wrapper
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the [peer dependency (@progress/kendo-ui)](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/).

Type `npm install --save @progress/kendo-ui` in your project folder and compile your frontend again to see if it fixes the error.

[Documentation Source](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui-wrappers/components/layout/#toc-dependencies)

Comment: I installed both the dependencies. But it doesn't work. I tried importing Button and it worked fine. So, its something to do with the Layout component.

Comment: @dschu just figured how to solve it. we need import `@pgroess/kendo-ui` explicitly once it is installed :)