# React Kendo UI TreeView throws 'kendo is not defined'

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am working on a React project with Kendo UI. I followed the steps from [Kendo UI TreeView](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/wrappers/treeview/)

I have installed `@progress/kendo-treeview-react-wrapper`, `@progress/kendo-ui` and imported theme into my project using `import '@progress/kendo-theme-material/dist/all.css';`

When I use KendoUI buttons, everything is working, the functionality and theme are expected, but it throws below Error when use `TreeView`

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: kendo is not defined
    at TreeView.componentDidMount (bundle.js:69556)
    at commitLifeCycles (bundle.js:12471)
    at commitAllLifeCycles (bundle.js:14142)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (bundle.js:2787)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (bundle.js:2825)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (bundle.js:2874)
    at commitRoot (bundle.js:14281)
    at completeRoot (bundle.js:15189)
    at performWorkOnRoot (bundle.js:15139)
    at performWork (bundle.js:15057)

bundle.js:12330 The above error occurred in the <TreeView> component:
    in TreeView (created by AssetsStatusTreeView)
    in div (created by AssetsStatusTreeView)
    in AssetsStatusTreeView (created by Connect(AssetsStatusTreeView))
    in Connect(AssetsStatusTreeView) (created by Route)
    in Route
    in Switch
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter
    in Provider
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at TreeView.KendoBaseComponent.componentWillUnmount (bundle.js:69569)
    at callComponentWillUnmountWithTimer (bundle.js:12390)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (bundle.js:2787)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (bundle.js:2825)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (bundle.js:2874)
    at safelyCallComponentWillUnmount (bundle.js:12397)
    at commitUnmount (bundle.js:12643)
    at unmountHostComponents (bundle.js:12986)
    at commitDeletion (bundle.js:13016)
    at commitAllHostEffects (bundle.js:14100)
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instructions from Kendo React is :

[image]

There's one more step to do, we need import `@progress/kendo-ui` explicitly:

```
import kendo from '@progress/kendo-ui';
```

The [Plunker Examples from KendoUI](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) helps me figure it out.